# Recognizing Class Parameters

Tags: python, class, visual-studio-code, kivy

I am working on learning to use an object oriented programming approach, which is new to me since I have mostly been working in a "procedural" capacity, which I have always had in one script or Jupyter Notebook. I am doing this through learning Kivy and how to build GUIs, but am running into issues where I have my main python code in one document, and parameters in another. The script and .kv file are in the same directory, but my issue is the script is not recognizing the .kv file in its directory. I am coding in visual studio and have my "main.py" script and my "TheLab.kv" file in the same directory, but when I run the main.py script, it does not seem to recognize .kv file with my parameters and runs as if the .kv file isn't specifying anything. Can you help me understand how to connect the script to .kv files, or specify class parameters so that I can call them in a separate script? When I run the script below (MVP), all I get is the same output as if the .kv file didn't exist at all.

**MVP**

***Python script:***

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

***.kv File***

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello World!"
        size: 400, 200
```

Comment: Try changing your `kv` file name to `thelab.kv` (No Caps).

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Just curious, for my own understanding, how does the python script call the .kv file without it being explicitly called out in the python script?

Comment: The `run()` method of the app calls the `load_kv()` method of the `App`, which constructs the `kv` file name as described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv).